# ¿Como pasar datos de un fragment a un Activity para enviarlos en un email en Android?

Tags: java, android-studio

Veran, tengo un `MainActivity` que una funcion que envia un email con los datos de un fragment. En este mi Fragment son inputs en los que se cargan datos. Ahora, en ese mismo fragment hay un boton de "Nuevos datos" que abre el mismo fragment pero con los campos limpios. Lo que necesito hacer es que en la funcion que esta en el `MainActivity` se envien los valores cargados en el primer fragment y en el fragment generado a partir del boton de "Nuevos datos". Alguna idea?

Comment: Cuidado con el mal uso de etiquetas, la etiqueta android-studio se refiere a problemas con el IDE, no con el codigo. Para pasar datos entre actividades o fragments, puedes usar los putExtra.

Comment: Tienes razón, voy a tener cuidado con eso, gracias!

Comment: **Hola, Harles, agrega lo que has intentado, por favor, te he sugerido en varias ocasiones realizar el [tour] y revisar [ask]**.